# To have a different opinion

Tags: meaning, sentence

I was watching a debate where at the end a member of the audience makes the statement:

> Is it not true that to have a different opinion is not the same as telling other people they can’t have an opinion?*

Can someone explain this as I cannot fully comprehend its meaning.

---

* “[Watch Fat Feminist Get Destroyed With Just One Question - Peter Hitchens](https://youtu.be/1q-jucUpjBQ)”. (Posted as a Youtube video on channel *MagiCal HD*, but based on their [fair use notice](https://www.youtube.com/channel/UC324f_2Yg8y_O0DXu4Bsp9Q/about) they are probably not the original publisher.)

Comment: What _do_ you understand about that sentence, and what do you have a problem with? The sentence as such seems quite straightforward, but if you have trouble understanding a specific part or aspect, we might be able to help you.

Comment: B says: 'Having a different opinion is not the same as telling other people they can’t have an opinion.' A says: 'That's not true.' A is wrong.

Comment: so someone just stated the obvious...but everyone gets hyped over that? I don’t understand the cheers I thought it was some major “put her in her place” revelation.

Comment: @oerkelens I think it’s the way it’s worded that just caused me confusion

Comment: The _is it not true that_ part is simply a rhetorical question. You may replace it with _the following fact is true:_. What follows is a simple statement: A is not the same as B.

Comment: I spend far too much time on the differnet, arguing away. I must give it up.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's something a lot of people don't understand.

Comment: FYI--the link is dead.

Comment: It's plain enough English to understand.

Answer (score 1):

"Is it not true that X" is an emphatic assertion that X is true. The rhetorical device is called [interrogatio/erotema](https://mannerofspeaking.org/2012/03/28/rhetorical-devices-erotema/):

> 7. interrogatio (erotema): the 'rhetorical question'
>    [- rhetotical figures](https://sites.ualberta.ca/%7Egepp/figures.html)
>
> A question that is asked without expecting an answer because the answer is strongly implied; a rhetorical question.
> [- Manner of Speaking](https://mannerofspeaking.org/2012/03/28/rhetorical-devices-erotema/)

Your quote emphatically asserts that the following are different ("is not the same"):

- to have a different opinion; and
- telling other people they can’t have an opinion

Answer (score 0):

The accurate transcription is:

> Is it not true that to have a different opinion isn't the same as telling other people that they shouldn't have, or they can't have an opinion?

This rhetorical question is from the debate about Freedom of Speech and Right to Offend on the Oxford Union Society where the speaker Kate Brooks was asked, then quickly lost her credibility via her response as a result.

Brooks is a DPhil (Doctor of Philosophy) candidate in the International Relations department at the University of Oxford.

Which, this question means:
Having a different opinion does not give you the authority to tell other people that they shouldn't/cannot have more opinions, don't you think?

So, basically; when you have an opinion on something, it does not cancel the other peoples' opinions by any means, does it?

In a way that, you do not have a golden/godly opinion that would finalise it, nor the other people must be silenced after you express your opinion, but on the contrary, the other people can and should have their opinions further, and you cannot stop this from happening forever.

The beginning part ("Is it not true" part) is not included in the question. So, if you move it to the end of the actual question, it may be more understandable.

Answer (score -2):

> Is it not true that to have a different opinion is not the same as telling other people they can’t have an opinion

use logic on it.
is it not true - is it fake? - (turns the answer to the other NOT gate)
that to have a - having a - (part of the question)
different opinion is not - different opinion isn't (opinion) - (expressed as if your opinion is not the same as the others is it is not...)
the same as telling - = telling - (is it the same as telling?)
other people they can't - not you can't - (others can't)
have an opinion - have an opinion - (finishing the question)

so it is simplified as. is it fake? having an opinion is the same as telling others they cant have an opinion? so because the second part means no the first part changes it to yes so the answer is yes.